# Getting error $ie8screen in video-js.scss

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, video.js

I have upgraded gem `rails-assets-videojs` to latest version `5.13.0` and after the upgrade, application start gave an error of `Undefined variable: "$ie8screen"`.

Help me to solution this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply import `videojs/alt/video-js-cdn` instead of `videojs` in your `application.css` file.

or you can define `$ie8screen` variable like this:

```
$ie8screen: "\\0screen";
```

before importing `videojs` in your `application.scss` file.